# Change backend/module at deploy time in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How would one go about implementing a replaceable backend (or basically any part or module) so that it can be replaced at configuration/deploy time in Elixir?

My specific situation is a simple web app (in this case using Phoenix but I'm guessing this question applies to other situations as well) where I have a very simple backend using `Agent` to keep state but I see a need in the future for being able to switch out the backend more or less dynamically.

I'm guessing both Ecto and Logger do this to some degree but being new to Elixir it's hard to know where to look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be handled through an argument to the supervisor. For example, Ecto's backend supervisor takes an argument called `adapter` to specify which kind of database should be used:

```
# https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/364d34bb135e2256fd48327464ada7f7fa2976f9/lib/ecto/repo/backend.ex#L13-L16

def start_link(repo, adapter) do
  # Start Ecto, depending on the supplied <repo> and <adapter>
end
```

You could do the same in your application, probably a single argument to `start_link` will be enough – let's call it `backend`

```
# my_app/lib/my_app/supervisor.ex

defmodule MyApp.Supervisor do
  def start_link(backend) do
    # use <backend> as you need to in here,
    # it will contain the module that is
    # specified in the configuration file.
  end
end
```

Now, you can of course set that argument dynamically when you spin up your application, based on a configuration file:

```
# my_app/lib/my_app.ex

defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    MyApp.Supervisor.start_link(backend)
  end

  # get backend from configuration
  def backend do
    # ???
  end
end
```

Now, the only piece that is missing is how to get the backend from a configuration file. There's no single answer to that because there are multiple ways of doing this.

#### Mix Configuration

You can simply use the existing Mix configuration, but it has the downside that you need to recompile the application every time the configuration changes:

```
# my_app/config/config.exs

use Mix.Config
config :my_app, backend: MyApp.SpecificBackend
```

Then adjust your application to read in the specified backend:

```
# my_app/lib/my_app.ex

defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    # same as above ...
  end

  def backend do
    Application.get_env(:my_app, :backend)
  end
end
```

#### Roll your own

You could also implement your own config file. I am not going into detail here, but this is the rough idea:

- Keep a config file somewhere
- Read an parse it in Elixir
- Convert the string to a module name with `String.to_existing_atom("Elixir.#{module_name}")`
- This will raise an error if the atom (thus the module name) does not exist
- use it in your `def backend` function

#### Use an existing run-time configuration library

Basically a glorified version of the previous solution. Googling around a bit I found a library called [Conform](https://github.com/bitwalker/conform). It looks interesting but I can'T make any promises because I've never used it myself.

Comment: Thank you, lots of good leads for me. I'm guessing I could also use mix' environments to have different backends?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, you are right. Of course you can also make the backend depend on your mix environment, but it will still require you to recompile the application when you change the environment.